# Android Toolbar Title

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-appbarlayout, android-titlebar

Unable to change toolbar title I set title in `manifeast.xml` & also used `setTitle("TITLE");`

I set title as **History & Reports** but it display different title **Notifications** which is another activity title.

I checked `manifeast.xml`  but No change, Can anyone please help me from this.

**Here is my code**

```
public class Nav_HistoryAndReports extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("History & Reports");
    setContentView(R.layout.nav_history_and_reports);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setToolbar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

public void setToolbar(Toolbar toolbar) {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentHistoryAndReports_Visits(), "VISITS");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentHistoryAndReports_Visitors(), "VISITORS");
    adapter.addFragment(new FragmentHistoryAndReports_Map(), "MAP");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:theme="@style/GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Please add code where you have set title "History".

Comment: I'm sorry title is History & Reports

Comment: Whatever title you have set add that code on your question.

Comment: You can find that in OnCreate Method where I added the code above

Comment: setTitle() after setToolbar()

Comment: Changed, but No Change

Comment: share your toolbar layout

Comment: Call `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("History & Reports");` at the end of, or after calling, your `setToolbar()` method.

Comment: It WORKS..!!! Thanks Mike M.

Answer (score 7):

Toolbar Title can be set in two ways

**1.In Layout XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout

android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:title="Main Activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_24dp"

        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**2. In Java** 
It will work in AppCompatActivity

```
Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("Notice Board"); 
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Make sure activity is AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 4):

I used below line to change the toolbar title

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("YOUR_TITLE");
```

Answer (score 1):

After this line `toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);` add `toolbar.setTitle("History & Reports");`

and remove `setTitle("History & Reports");`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but No Change

Comment: @Listo add this also with Rachit suggestion getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1):

Set title in your layout as i did below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
        app:theme="@style/GalaxyZooThemeToolbarDarkOverflow">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

and in your activity simply set the toolbar and disable its default title as follows

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null)
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding getsupportActionBar().setTitle();

Comment: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` - They're already using a `NoActionBar` theme.

Answer (score 0):

Litle change your code look like this..

```
 toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setToolbar(toolbar);
```

And after setToolbar look

```
 public void setToolbar(Toolbar toolbar) {
    toolbar.setTitle("History & Reports");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As **Mike M** said

I just added `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("History & Reports");` at the end of, or after calling, your setToolbar() method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.calender));
```

This one work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you use toolbar that supports `actionBar`, you should do as the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_favorite);

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

try {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: back button not supported!");
}

// here you set your activity title
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Activity Title");
```