# How to use with CollapsingLayout with Navigation Advanced Example

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to integrate Collapsing layout with [Navigation Advanced example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample)

**What I tried?**

Added Collapsing bar layout to main_actvity.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Modified `setupBottomNavigationBar()` in [MainActivity.kt](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/MainActivity.kt)

```
private fun setupBottomNavigationBar(){

...
controller.observe(this, Observer { navController ->

            mainBinding.collapsingToolbarLayout.setupWithNavController(mainBinding.toolbar, navController)
            //setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
        })
...
}
```

**Current issue:**

Now I have two ActionBars instead of one. Top one have app name as the title, one below shows nothing initially but when navigated to an sub destination only a grey back arrow is shown, no destination label is shown on the actionbar

Anyone who understand this multiple backstack implementation, please help me to get things work with `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

**Update**:

Got rid of one action bar as @Manoj suggested in a comment, Now need to fix not appearing of titles in the actionbar

**Update 2**:

Although the destination labels(titles) are not shown when navigated to sub destinations, but back button is shown.

Comment: you should remove the other toolbar from styles

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Thanks for reaching out. actually I do not have any styles applied to toolbar `appTheme` parent is `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: @ManojPerumarath got rid of one actionbar, updated the question a bit

Comment: What's your need

Comment: need to get titles to show up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42919123/android-toolbar-title

Comment: does not work, even if it worked its repetitive and annoying to set title manually, no point of having destination labels in nav graph if we need to set things manually

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally figured out why the toolbar title was not shown reason was I have not set enough height for appbar layout, I was using `wrap_content` so collapsing toolbar layout was covering the toolbar title. Solution was to set appbar layout height to value larger than 64dp. When I increased the appbar layout height, it looks unusually tall. (Forgive me for my lack of understanding of how collapsing toolbar works)

But this was not my intention, I wanted to enable collapsing toolbar for some specific fragments, I was using single activity concepts as navigation architecture component recommends.

As I read in following answers

1. [Having two toolbars and making one transparent when doing fragment transactions.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44978781/7356355)
2. [Having separate toolbar for each fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44722385/7356355)

IMHO Both of these are not good solutions if you are using navigation architecture component, there is no value of using navigation architecture component, if you need to manage fragment transactions or toolbars manually.

So for now I have stop using collapsing toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

if the title is not displayed (and that increasing the appbar layout height "works"), just set the isTitleEnabled of the collapsingToolbarLayout to false.
It should fix the problem